# Error while uploading to firestore cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.getcount = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const dstname = data.dstname;
    var count={uq:0,qc:0};
    function test2(callback) {
    db.doc(`Kerala/${dstname}`).listCollections().then((snap) => {
      return Promise.all(snap.map((collection) => {
          var col = collection.id;
          return db
          .collection(`Kerala/${dstname}/${col}`).where("completionStatus", "<", 3).get().then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.forEach((doc) => {var data = doc.data();
                console.log(data.place);
                if (data.completionStatus === 0) count.uq++;
                else count.qc++;
                })
              });
           })
        );
      }).then(callback);
    }
    test2(function () {return count;});
});
```

I tried to deploy this to cloud using firebase deploy --only function command. But I get these errors

```
24:5   error    Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
27:18  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
28:96  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
39:11  warning  Unexpected function expression              prefer-arrow-callback

✖ 4 problems (2 errors, 2 warnings)
0 errors and 1 warning potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

Any help would be thankful.

Comment: You have two errors and two warnings coming from eslint.  I suggest doing google searches for each of those messages and codes to find out more about what they mean, then tackle them individually.

Comment: Thank You..your suggestion helped. I could fix those both errors @DougStevenson